# undefined method `html_safe' for #<String:0x1042222c0> using recaptcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha, nomethoderror, html-safe

I'm getting this error on the line where I call `recaptcha_tags`

```
<%= recaptcha_tags( :public_key => 'XXXXXXYYYYYYYZZZ-ZXYXXZYZ' , :display=>{:theme=>"white" }) %>
```

I'm working with `rails 2.3.10`

how can I solve this error?

many thanks.

Comment: Use a version of recaptcha that is compatible with Rails 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i did what's specified here https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/issues/30 and worked out perfectly for me

```
Changing client_helper.rb line 39 to:
return (html.respond_to?(:html_safe) && html.html_safe) || html
fixes the issue.
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 2.3.x, html_safe is defined as a String class method in:

activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb

Make sure that you have the proper active_support version (one matching your rails version).